# Getting System.QueryException: line 1:40 no viable alternative at character '\'

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce

Am using a dynamic query to get data. Below is my code

```
if(objVal != null){
      sObject obj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objVal).newSObject();
      if(ConditionVal== null || ConditionVal=='')
     query = 'Select Id From '+objVal+ ' Limit 10000';
        else{
           ConditionVal= String.escapeSingleQuotes(ConditionVal);
           query = 'Select Id From '+selectedObj+' WHERE '+ConditionVal+' LIMIT 10000';
        }      
        List<SObject> objlst = Database.query(query);
```

Am getting "objVal" , "ConditionVal" value form VF page
Example objVal = 'Account' ConditionVal = 'industry = 'Apparel'
after executing the code am getting the query like this

```
Select Id From Account WHERE industry = \'Apparel\' LIMIT 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

update the value of ConditionVal variable as below,

ConditionVal = 'Industry = \'Apparel\'';

the query will work as expected.